# Kotlin - Best way to call createExceptionAndAwait() inside exchangeToFlow

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux

I have the following weblux client call and since exchangeToFlow is not a suspending function, what's the best way to call use createExceptionAndAwait() inside it?

```
return webClient.post()
      .uri(url)
      .bodyValue(body)
      .accept(APPLICATION_JSON)
      .exchangeToFlow {
        if (!it.statusCode().is2xxSuccessful) {
          throw httpExceptionHandlerUtil.handleException(it.createExceptionAndAwait())
        }
        it.bodyToFlow()
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use Spring, so this is a total guess.

The output of the lambda is a Flow, so you can wrap it all in a `flow` builder like this so you can call suspend functions:

```
.exchangeToFlow {
  flow {
    if (!it.statusCode().is2xxSuccessful) {
      throw httpExceptionHandlerUtil.handleException(it.createExceptionAndAwait())
    }
    emitAll(it.bodyToFlow())
  }
}
```

Comment: Note, the exception won't be thrown until this is collected, and it will throw each time it is collected if it has more than one collector.

Comment: it did the trick! thank you so much! @Tenfour04